# gawk string extract between ([:alnum][:alnum][:alnum] and [:alnum])

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I'm trying to get the string between `"([:alnum][:alnum][:alnum]" and ")"` and the string itself. The idea in fact is to clean a file that is polluted with many unwanted char.

For example I have many lines with something like :

```
bÖÓÄÉ@@@@ø16/11/2016 15H03'09" (ACTA/BN940-RYR71ND/A4067-LIPH-NILDU/1513F270-LEBL-9/B738/M-80/S-81/W/EQ Y/EQ)   ø     ZZZZtA$bÖÓÄÉ
```

And I want this kind of output :

```
(ACTA/BN940-RYR71ND/A4067-LIPH-NILDU/1513F270-LEBL-9/B738/M-80/S-81/W/EQ Y/EQ)
```

I tried with this gawk command but it doesn't work at all :

```
gawk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' RS='([[:alnum:]]*3' FS=')' $INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: why not `grep -oP '\(.*\)' inputfile` ? this will print anything between `(` and `)`. or `grep -oP '\(\K.*(?=\))' inputfile` if you do not want `( & )` in your outptu.

Comment: The file contains many parasite chars like " H@@@@A@" that are detected as brackets... That's why I need a more complex pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a standard use of GNU grep:

```
grep -o '([[:alnum:]]\{3\}.*[[:alnum:]])' file
```

There were some problems with your regular expression syntax, which I've corrected.

The `-o` option prints only the matching part of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Thats' exactly what I needed.